# Trie C++ Strings not completely filling all the values in a text file

Tags: c++, string, sorting, trie, radix-sort

i'm trying to sort a large amount of strings alphabetically and by length and it seems i'm only sorting around 1/7 of the amount needed. I am trying to sort around 100,000 words, when I sorted 70000 I ended up with 8000 words sorted and can't seem to find why it isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
            char value;             // the character value
            bool end;               // indicates whether this node completes a word
            Node * children[93];    // represents the 93 ascii values for 33-126
            Node(char newChar);
            ~Node();
};

class Trie
{
    public:
            Trie();
        ~Trie();
            void addWord(string word);
            Node * getRoot();
    private:
            Node * root;
};

Node::Node(char newChar)
{
    value = newChar;

        for (int i = 0; i < 93; ++i)
            children[i] = NULL;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    delete[] children;
}

Trie::Trie()
{
    root = new Node(' ');
    root->end = true;
}

Trie::~Trie()
{
    delete root;
}

Node * Trie::getRoot()
{
    return root;
}

void Trie::addWord(string word)
{
    Node * currentNode = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i)
    {
        char currentChar = word.at(i);
        int index = currentChar - '!';

        if (currentNode->children[index] != NULL)
        {
                currentNode = currentNode->children[index];
        }

        else
        {
                Node * newNode = new Node(currentChar);
                currentNode->children[index] = newNode;
                currentNode = newNode;
        }

        if (i == word.size() - 1)
        {
                currentNode->end = true;
        }
    }
}

void alphabetize(Node * node, vector<string> & sorting, string prefix = "") //why dont i have to declare this?
{
        if (node->end)
        {
            sorting.push_back(prefix);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 93; ++i)
    {
        if (node->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            string currentString = prefix + node->children[i]->value; //store all characters
                alphabetize(node->children[i], sorting, currentString);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Trie * t = new Trie();
    string tempS;

    int lengthCounter = 0;
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("test.txt");

    vector< vector<string> > sortLength;
    vector <string> row(0, "");
    vector<string> sorted;

    while(fin >> tempS)
    {
        while(tempS.length() > lengthCounter)
        {
                sortLength.push_back(row);
                lengthCounter++;
        }
        t->addWord(tempS);
    }

        alphabetize(t->getRoot(),sorted); //filled with sorted vector

        for(int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++)
        {
            sortLength[sorted[i].length()-1].push_back(sorted[i]);
        }


        for(int k = 0; k < sortLength.size(); k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < sortLength[k].size(); l++)
            {
                cout << sortLength[k][l] << "\n";
            }
        }

        cout << sorted.size();


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delete[] children;` This doesn't do what you think it does, `delete[]` will delete arrays allocated with `new[]`, if you want to `delete` the elements that `children` points to you will have to loop over the array and `delete` each one individually. Then again you almost certainly shouldn't be handling raw arrays and pointers in the first place. Turn your compiler warnings on.

Comment: I didn't expect it would do what I think, but I didn't think that it matters with my problem, its really just there

Comment: Why in `alphabetize` you use `for (int i = 0; i < 93; ++i)`? what `93` stands for?

Comment: It should be base 128 shouldn't it? I did it for values 33-126 on the ascii table